Hibernate Envers Auditing BLOB/TEXT Column Key Length Issue
I am working on a project to enable Hibernate Envers auditing in our codebase. We are using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update to generate the audit tables automatically.
However, it auto-generates audit tables for all entities except for this @ElementCollection mapping:
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "user_property", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false))
@MapKeyColumn(name = "property", length = 255)
@Column(name = "property_value", length = Integer.MAX_VALUE)
@Cascade({ CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.EVICT })
private Map<String, String> userProperties;

I am encountering the following error when trying to run the application with auditing enabled for this collection:
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    create table user_property_AUD (
       REV integer not null,
        user_id integer not null,
        property_value longtext not null,
        property varchar(255) not null,
        REVTYPE tinyint,
        primary key (REV, user_id, property_value, property)
    ) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:526) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:728) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:746) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:616) ~[spring-orm-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:600) ~[spring-orm-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.openmrs.api.db.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateSessionFactoryBean.java:190) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91) ~[spring-aop-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:111) ~[spring-aop-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:96) ~[spring-aop-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:78) ~[spring-aop-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:341) ~[spring-aop-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:293) ~[spring-aop-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) [spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) [spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) [spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:775) [spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:571) [spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:399) [spring-web-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.openmrs.web.Listener.contextInitialized(Listener.java:255) [classes/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1068) [jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:572) [jetty-servlet-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:997) [jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:746) [jetty-servlet-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379) [jetty-servlet-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1457) [jetty-webapp-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:328) [jetty-maven-plugin-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1422) [jetty-webapp-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:911) [jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288) [jetty-servlet-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524) [jetty-webapp-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:397) [jetty-maven-plugin-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73) [jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169) [jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117) [jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97) [jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73) [jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169) [jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117) [jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97) [jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73) [jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169) [jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423) [jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110) [jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97) [jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387) [jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73) [jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:449) [jetty-maven-plugin-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:310) [jetty-maven-plugin-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:150) [jetty-maven-plugin-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126) [maven-core-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:328) [maven-core-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:316) [maven-core-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212) [maven-core-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:174) [maven-core-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:75) [maven-core-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:162) [maven-core-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39) [maven-core-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:159) [maven-core-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105) [maven-core-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73) [maven-core-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53) [maven-core-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118) [maven-core-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261) [maven-core-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173) [maven-core-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101) [maven-core-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:906) [maven-embedder-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:283) [maven-embedder-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:206) [maven-embedder-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:283) [plexus-classworlds-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:226) [plexus-classworlds-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:407) [plexus-classworlds-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:348) [plexus-classworlds-2.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47) [plexus-classworlds-2.7.0.jar:?]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: BLOB/TEXT column 'property_value' used in key specification without a key length
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.execute(NewProxyStatement.java:75) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    ... 139 more

Extra Informations
DDL mapping for user_properties table
create table user_property
(
    user_id        int default 0 not null,
    property       varchar(255)  not null,
    property_value longtext      null,
    primary key (user_id, property),
    constraint user_property_to_users
        foreign key (user_id) references users (user_id)
);


Java version: 1.8
Hibernate version: 5.6.15.Final
Spring version: 5.3.30

